How can i add a section of html for the user to enter payment details that will be encrypted?
I have created a simple looking form where the user will need to enter tickets to book a theme park. I need to figure out how to add payments details and encrypt them.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Theme park Booking System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #f3f3f3;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        .container {
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
        .card {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="text-center">Book Your Theme park Visit</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="/book" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="date">Select Date:</label>
                        <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ticket_type">Select Ticket Type:</label>
                        <select name="ticket_type" class="form-control" required>
                            <option value="child">Child</option>
                            <option value="adult">Adult</option>
                            <option value="oap">OAP</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="num_tickets">Number of Tickets:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="num_tickets" class="form-control" min="1" required>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Book Tickets</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

I would also like to make the form look better for the user so it is easy to understand.
I have created a simple form to purchase theme park tickets. I have tried to make payment form but i cant get it to work yet

encryption or anything that requires security is not a task for frontend/client-side. As such it can and should never be solved with HTML.

The very first requirement for a payment form would be an SSL certificate which is not a programmer question. If you have that, it would be questionable if you need encryption at all. If you do, then it would be an encryption server-sided where not everyone could read out the encryption key. The question is, if they payment details need to be saved encrypted on a database while the bills remain unencrypted. The only place where you "encrypt"  or more specifically hide most part of the card-number is when sending an email (still backend task).
